# iFrame browser issue while including a JSP file inside another JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, iframe, cross-browser

I have an iFrame in a JSP file to display PDF files, where as I am including this page in another JSP file and trying to display the same. It is working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. Here by I have attached the script and html content.

Script :

```
function displayAttachmentInIframe(attachmentPath)
{
   var iframeElementId = '#employeeDetailsAttachmentDisplayIFrame';
   var iframeElementStyleClass = 'margin-top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 400px;
   border:0px; overflow-x: hidden;';
   jQuery(iframeElementId).attr('src', attachmentPath);
   jQuery(iframeElementId).attr('style', iframeElementStyleClass);
}
```

HTML Code :

```
<iframe id="employeeDetailsAttachmentDisplayIFrame"/>
<h:graphicImage id="employeeDetailsAttachmentImage"
                url="#{EmployeeDetails.attachedFilePath}"
                alt="Attachment Not Found"
                style="width: 580px; height: 400px;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `chrome` and `IE`, you may not load `http://` content inside `https://` page directly unless user acknowledges it. Make sure you have `SSL` certificate for your `https://` urls. You can check the error in `chrome console`.